# how to use the slice operator to change element in nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, slice

```
testlist = [1, 4, 9, 'sixteen', ['25', '...']]
```

I want to use the slice operator to change the last element of the nested list to 36. how do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as follows:

```
>>> testlist = [1 , 4 , 9 , 'sixteen ', ['25 ', '... ']]
>>> testlist[-1][-1] = '36'
[1, 4, 9, 'sixteen', ['25', '...', '36']]
```

If you simply want to add on as the last element instead of replace, do: `testlist[-1].append('36')` instead

In lists, the `-1` index gets the last element of a list. However, if your nested list is not always last, you can do:

```
>>> testlist[i][-1] = '36
```

where `i` is the position of the nested list in `testlist`. More generally, you can do:

```
>>> testlist[i][j] = '36'
```

where `i` fetches the `ith` element in `testlist` and `j` fetches the `jth` element in the `ith` element.

#### Examples

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]    #note the nested lists
>>> a[1][1]
4
>>> a[-1][-1]
6
>>> a[-1][0]
5
>>> a[0][-1]
2
```